# Python check parameters is a list of a certain objects

Tags: python

Trying to implement a function to take a list of certain objects only, but cant seem to implement it.

So lets say we have a function testing:

```
def testing(myTypes=None):
    if myTypes:
        if isinstance(myTypes, list) and all([isinstance(item, myType) for item in myTypes]):
            print("Correct")
        else:
            print("myTypes must be a list of myType object only")
    else:
        print("No myTypes provided")

class myType:
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"

testing()
testing(['xd'])
testing([myType.a, myType.b])
```

The output is:

```
No myTypes provided
myTypes must be a list of myType object only
myTypes must be a list of myType object only
```

But I want the last one to have an output of "Correct".  Yes, I know I am ultimately sending a string in the parameter, thus its not a `myType` object, but cant seem to figure out how it should be done.

So two questions:

1. If I want to implement it in such a way, how could it be done.
2. In the end, all I really want to do is to limit certain valid strings to be valid options to the myTypes, but I figured putting it in a class would be best, so say users can easily see the available members/options of myType, using intellisense of their IDE.  In short, what would be the best way to achieve this goal.  And yes it will be easy to have a set of strings and check if all the strings provided in the `myTypes` exists in that set, but the users will need to know this list, typos can occur, and its just easier to have a class (imo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `myType` to an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#creating-an-enum):

```
from enum import Enum

class myType(Enum):
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
```

I now get this output:

```
No myTypes provided
myTypes must be a list of myType object only
Correct
```

With `myType` as an `Enum`, `myType.a` is now different than `"a"`. This causes your second example to still fail, but your third example will now be correct. An `Enum` also represents a strongly typed fixed set of values, which is a perfect use case to "limit certain valid strings to be valid options".

Note that you should rename `myType` to `MyType` and capitalize the `a`, `b` and `c`. This is the convention for `Enum`s.